# Sublime Text How to add package to global repository

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

I created a plugin for sublime and I called it "sublimecastling".
The main idea is to replace 2 selected fields.

So I'll be glad to know whether it's possible to add it to your Sublime repository in order users could install the plugin via package-control.

The github link is provided below,

https://github.com/unknownuser88/sublimecastling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to make a plugin available via Package Control, visit the [documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/docs) page on the Package Control website and click on [Submitting a Package](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/submitting_a_package). There are a number of steps, which can be summarized as follows:

1. Search Package Control to ensure your package fulfills an unmet need, or greatly improves upon an existing package - don't create a new one (especially a very simple one) when you could work with the author of an existing one to add a particular feature.
2. Pick a name - there are several requirements here.
3. Decide how to host - Github? Bitbucket? Your own SSL server?

   *my own note here: Github is easiest*
4. Pick a versioning strategy using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/). Note that all new packages must release by using versioning tags, not by branches or commits.
5. Prepare your repo - several things to do here.
6. Fork the Package Control Channel on Github and add your repo to the default channel - detailed instructions included.
7. Run the [`ChannelRepositoryTools`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ChannelRepositoryTools) package in Sublime to make sure everything is OK.

   *Note: Test your package with both [ST2](http://sublimetext.com/2) and [ST3](http://sublimetext.com/3) to make sure it works with both versions of Sublime. If you can only support one version due to the language differences between Python 2.6 and 3.3, pick ST3 - it is the future of Sublime, has a very large user base already, and will get you maximum exposure. If you haven't personally upgraded to ST3, now is the time to do so. If you are a registered user—which you should be :)—test with both the [public beta](http://sublimetext.com/3) and the latest [dev build](http://sublimetext.com/3dev).*
8. Finally, you can submit your pull request.

   *Be patient, it may take a little while for it to be reviewed, and it is not uncommon at all for changes to be requested. It is by following strict procedures that the community maintains the high quality of the packages available for users.*

Comment: Please describe the instructions. The link you have provided doesn't show them.

Comment: @JulianMoreno thanks for the feedback. Please see my edit.